# MySQL-python installation error using pip2.7

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have installed Python2.7,virtualenv and pip2.7 in centos6.4 64bit as python2.6 is a default one.

when i try to install mysqldb using

```
pip2.7 install MySQL-python
```

error occurs and python-devel package is already installed.

> ```
> _mysql.c:2551: error: '_mysql_ConnectionObject' has no member named 'open'
>
> _mysql.c:2558: error: '_mysql_ConnectionObject' has no member named 'converter'
>
> _mysql.c:2565: error: '_mysql_ConnectionObject' has no member named 'connection'
>
> _mysql.c:2572: error: '_mysql_ConnectionObject' has no member named 'connection'
>
> _mysql.c:2579: error: '_mysql_ConnectionObject' has no member named 'connection'
>
> _mysql.c:2642: error: '_mysql_ResultObject' has no member named 'converter'
>
> _mysql.c:2642: error: initializer element is not constant
>
> _mysql.c:2642: error: (near initialization for '_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[0].offset')
>
> _mysql.c: In function '_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattr':
>
> _mysql.c:2666: error: '_mysql_ConnectionObject' has no member named 'open'
>
> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ----------------------------------------
> Cleaning up...
> Command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
> ```
>
> 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-eNCiSQ-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/MySQL-python
>       Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

Comment: If you're still looking for a solution to this problem, you may have better luck on another StackExchange site, http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't have the mysql-devel package installed, which is required so that the uncompiled source and header files are available to the MySQL-python package.

As root, run

```
yum install mysql-devel
```

and try again!

Comment: I was having the same issue and this was just what I needed! Thanks!!